# Symfony2 validatePropertyValue for UniqueEntity

Tags: validation, symfony

Is there a way validate UniqueEntity on a single property value for symfony validator?

```yaml
# Acme\Resources\config\validation.yml
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: { fields: username, message: This username is already taken}

    properties:
        username:
            - NotBlank: { message: You must provide a username}
```

When I run validation on the on the User Registration form it works perfectly, checking `NotBlank` then `UniqueEntity` and reporting violations.

But, I also run ajax validation on each field (as users type) using validator and `validatePropertyValue` as follows:

```php
$violations = $this->validator->validatePropertyValue("Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User", "username", $value);

var_dump($violations);
```

only the properties username contraint is ever checked. It never checks against the `uniqueEntity` constraint.

Comment: You can use $this->validator->validate() in AJAX validation. Why you validate each property?

Comment: to validate each field on blur.

Comment: I was able to get it work by populating the object with the single property and using validate() then filtering the violations on the propertyPath to get it to work. Just not the most elegant way to validate a single property.